# Problem Symfony/Doctrine : One-To-Many - Self-referencing on a primary key

Tags: symfony, doctrine, primary-key

I would like to have a "post" with an identifier. This one could be classified in another "post" by storing the identifier of his parent.

I tried to do like this:

```
class Post {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="Id_Post_Parent")
     */
    private $Id_Post;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="Id_Post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Id_Post", referencedColumnName="Id_Post", nullable=true)
     */
    private $Id_Post_Parent;
    ...
}
```

but I have this error when i'm checking with `doctrine:schema:validate` :

> [FAIL] The entity-class App\Entity\Post mapping is invalid:
>
> - The association App\Entity\Post#Id_Post_Parent refers to the inverse side field App\Entity\Post#Id_Post which is not defined as association.
> - The association App\Entity\Post#Id_Post_Parent refers to the inverse side field App\Entity\Post#Id_Post which does not exist.
> - The referenced column name 'Id_Post' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Entity\Post'.

Can someone help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is small logical error with your structure - your ID_Post variable tries to be both the primary key (the ID) and the collection association side. I didn't check this syntax in too much details (you can find an example of this association along with most of the other associations from doctrine documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing), but basically you need to add the children association separately to your entity like this:

```
class Post 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="postChildren")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_parent_post", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $postParent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="postParent")
     */
    private $postChildren;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->postChildren = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to get a recursive entity on the Id ? Actually I wanted to get the Id of another post into each one

Comment: it is referencing to the ID of the parent post entity - that part is visible in the $Post_parent join column definition 'referencedColumnName="Id_Post". I.e. this entity structure will generate in the database columns "Id_Post" (the post id) and "Id_Parent_Post" (the foreign key reference to the parent post id). Assuming that "recursive entity" means "self-referencing entity" that is.

Comment: Ok thanks ! But with your solution, I still have this error : `The referenced column name 'Id_Post' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Entity\Post'.`

Do you know why ?

Comment: Are you using doctrine to generate the database structure from the entities or have you defined your table separately? Namely, do you have column with name "Post_Id" in the related database table for posts?

Comment: Yes i'm using doctrine to generate the database structure from the entities.
And I don't have any column "Post_Id", only "Id_Post" like in our previously postes, with Id and GeneratedValue for ORM.

Comment: ah, I just typoed the field name the wrong away around in my comment there. But that's fine, you answered to the question in any case. I haven't checked how doctrine handles the capitalized member variable names when generating the column names so there might be some mismatch due to that - I updated the example above to use the names without the capitals (if you don't want to regenerate the schema - you can also just check what the actual database column name is for the id: and if it is "id_post" (without capitals), update the "referencedColumnName" to use this uncapitalized version.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this evening and I'll make you a return.